# IP-cam RTSP on eth1 forwarding to eth0

Tags: networking

I have an IP-cam 192.168.55.60 on eth1 while eth0 (192.168.1.101) is connected to my router (192.168.1.1)

In order to play my RTSP camera stream I need to access rtsp://192.168.55.60/av0_1

I want to access this stream from my devices connected to the router subnet (192.168.1.1). How can I do this? The RTSP server use both TCP and UDP

Comment: Can you set camera to use DHCP? If not add alias to network card with IP from 192.168.55 network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) using `iptables`.
As user root:

1. On your machine, enable routing:

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
2. On your machine, NAT using iptables:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.55.60 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
3. On the machines that want access to the IP-cam, indicate the route towards your IP-cam:

   ```
   ip route add 192.168.55.60 via 192.168.1.101
   ```